# How can I get input side by side in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope['rfpq.mailRecievers']}" var="row">
<tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp; </td>
<td style="color: #000000; font-size: 11px;" height="17" width="450">  &nbsp;${row} |</td> 

</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Input is:

A0001 |

A0002 |

A0003 |

A0004 |

A0005 |

How will I get input like(with colors):

A0001 | (color: gray) A0002 | A0003 | (color: gray) A0004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${requestScope['rfpq.mailRecievers']}" var="row" varStatus="status"  >
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${status.count%2==0}">
                    <td style="color: #000000; font-size: 11px;" height="17">   &nbsp;${row} |</td> 
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <td style="color: gray; font-size: 11px;" height="17">   &nbsp;${row}|</td> 
                 </c:otherwise>
             </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use the `varStatus`  attribute to access the [LoopTagStatus](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) instance  for the current `<c:forEach>`, and its `count` property gives you the loop counter. The you can use this loop counter to style your odd column and even column.

Comment: I've already tried this but my table bombs when I write this.

Comment: Also I wrote:
<table height="500" width="500"> has same problem,table bombs.

Comment: it seems that you want to style the odd column and even column too , just updated